# How to send ctrl+shift+6 as ansi escape sequence?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, cisco, ansi-escape, windows-terminal

Trying to find the ANSI escape sequence for sending the keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> in the format `\u001b`.. .

I recently tried switching over to only using Windows Terminal instead of SecureCRT/Putty but i'm having issues terminating Cisco telnet/console sessions that uses <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> and then <kbd>x</kbd>.

The terminal does not seem to recognize this or isn't forwarding it the same way as SecureCRT/Putty because nothing happens. The session is established over term VTY100 if that has any use, and the SSH-session is initiated from a Zsh-shell in a Redhat7 jumphost, the base connection comes from my Ubuntu WSL2-box.

I think I found a possible workaround as Windows Terminals allows keybinding an ansi escape sequence, but I'm unable to figure out what the sequence would look like?

> Send arbitrary text input to the shell. As an example the input `"text\n"` will write "text" followed by a newline to the shell.
>
> ANSI escape sequences may be used, but escape codes like `\x1b` must be written as `\u001b`. For instance `"\u001b[A"` will behave as if the up arrow button had been pressed.

By default this exact keybinding is used by Windows Terminal to open a new tab but I removed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is

> Trying to find the ASCII escape sequence for sending the keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> in the format `\u001b`.. .

That's referring to <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>**`^`**</kbd>, which usually is **`0x1e`** (hexadecimal) or **`036`** (octal).

Based on the comment which you quoted, that would be expressed as "\u001e".

If Windows Terminal assigns that to a different code, you might open a bug report, because its developers intend to imitate **`xterm`**.

Comment: I´ve been banging my head against this for a day, thank you! It worked perfectly, for anyone else wondering my keybind looks like this now:

`{ "command": { "action": "sendInput", "input": "\u001e" }, "keys": "f5" }`